# Emulating an empty queryset with an abstract model

Tags: python, django, drf-spectacular

I have a use case in which I have a ListAPIView that connects to a 3rd party (Stripe) API, fetches data (invoices) and returns that data to the user. I have a serializer, but I don't have a model.

The entire code looks something like this:

```py
class InvoicesList(generics.ListAPIView):
  serializer_class = InvoiceSerializer

  def get_queryset(self):
    if getattr(self, 'swagger_fake_view', False):
      return   # <----  ¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?
  
    return StripeWrapper().get_invoices()

class InvoiceSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
  ...fields..
  ...fields...
  ...fields

class StripeWrapper():
  def get_invoices():
   return requests.get(......)
```

Since I don't have a model, `drf-spectacular` refuses to generate the proper openapi specs. It expects to receive an `EmptyQuerySet` (`SomeModel.objects.none()`), but I can't provide it any since I don't have an `Invoice` model. I could create an abstract model like this:

```py
class Invoice(models.Model):
  class Meta:
    abstract = True
```

but I still won't be able to provide `drf-spectacular` with an `Invoice.objects.none()` since there is no manager in that class (and there can't be since it's abstract).

How can I "emulate" (¿?) or "generate" an `EmptyQuerySet` so I can workaround this issue?

Comment: Opinion: Don't do work when others have done it for you. https://github.com/dj-stripe/dj-stripe

Comment: I am using dj-stripe. Nevertheless, I expose dj-stripe's functionality with the code I posted.